# Multiple rows with same ID in Silverstripe GridField

Tags: silverstripe

is there a way to group a GridField (for example, by ID)? The following Query (many_many) returns some dataobjects twice or more, if they havent the same SortOrder. Here is some code. I hope that somebody can help ;-)

```
private static $many_many = array(
    'Mitarbeiter'         => 'Mitarbeiter',
);

private static $many_many_extraFields = array(
    'Mitarbeiter' => array(
        'SortOrder' => "Int"
    )
)

        // Start Mitarbeiterzuordnung
        $MitarbeiterFieldConfig = GridFieldConfig::create()->addComponents(
          new GridFieldToolbarHeader(),
          //new GridFieldSortableHeader(),
          new GridFieldDataColumns(),
          new GridFieldDeleteAction('unlinkrelation'),
          new GridFieldSortableRows('SortOrder'),
          new GridFieldManyRelationHandler(), 'GridFieldPaginator',
          new GridFieldPaginator(20)
        );
        $MitarbeiterField = new GridField("Mitarbeiter", "Mitarbeiter", $this->Mitarbeiter()->sort('SortOrder'), $MitarbeiterFieldConfig);
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Mitarbeiter', $MitarbeiterField);
```

Comment: have you tried setting up a `Mitarbeiter()` method that returns `$this->getManyManyComponents('Mitarbeiter')->sort('SortOrder')`. Then in `new GridField` you simply use `$this->Mitarbeiter()`. This seems to be the standard way to have `GridFieldSortableRows` setup...

Comment: yes, i have put  
    public function Mitarbeiter() {
        return     $this->getManyManyComponents('Mitarbeiter')->sort('SortOrder');
}

after public function getCMSFields() {

But without success?
    }

Comment: and did you change `$this->Mitarbeiter()->sort('SortOrder')` to `$this->Mitarbeiter()` in the `new GridField(..` statement?

Comment: yes, i did: $MitarbeiterField = new GridField("Mitarbeiter", "Mitarbeiter", $this->Mitarbeiter(), $MitarbeiterFieldConfig);

Comment: I would imagine the code comes from somewhere else than the GridField. Do you mind putting a link to the code for `Mitarbeiter`

Comment: http://www.webathleten.de/art-hamm/Mitarbeiter.txt

Comment: I can't actually reproduce your error. All works fine for me. I do have it setup like mentioned in my first comment though. Only thing I can think of, is maybe your DataObjects actually exist in duplicate? Where/How do you create the `Mitarbeiter` entries? Have you check the DB?

Comment: i have checked it in the DB. No duplicate entries!???

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with GridFieldManyRelationHandler.php and having a `private static $many_many_extraFields` as sorting field.

The query runs with the SortOrder being different and because it uses distinct, the ones having a different values are seen as extra, this is why the ones that have an order set show up twice.

You need to create a copy of GridFieldManyRelationHandler.php (I called it GridFieldManyManyRelationHandler.php) and edit the following function:

```
    public function getManipulatedData(GridField $gridField, SS_List $list) {
    if(!$list instanceof RelationList) {
        user_error('GridFieldManyRelationHandler requires the GridField to have a RelationList. Got a ' . get_class($list) . ' instead.', E_USER_WARNING);
    }

    $state = $this->getState($gridField);

    // We don't use setupState() as we need the list
    if($state->FirstTime) {
        $state->RelationVal = array_values($list->getIdList()) ?: array();
    }
    if(!$state->ShowingRelation && $this->useToggle) {
        return $list;
    }

    $baseClass = $list->dataClass();
    return $baseClass::get();


}
```

Then call that new class from your code, ie

```
private static $many_many = array(
    'Mitarbeiter'         => 'Mitarbeiter',
);

private static $many_many_extraFields = array(
    'Mitarbeiter' => array(
        'SortOrder' => "Int"
    )
)

        // Start Mitarbeiterzuordnung
        $MitarbeiterFieldConfig = GridFieldConfig::create()->addComponents(
          new GridFieldToolbarHeader(),
          //new GridFieldSortableHeader(),
          new GridFieldDataColumns(),
          new GridFieldDeleteAction('unlinkrelation'),
          new GridFieldSortableRows('SortOrder'),
          new GridFieldManyManyRelationHandler(), 'GridFieldPaginator',
          new GridFieldPaginator(20)
        );
        $MitarbeiterField = new GridField("Mitarbeiter", "Mitarbeiter", $this->Mitarbeiter()->sort('SortOrder'), $MitarbeiterFieldConfig);
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Mitarbeiter', $MitarbeiterField);
```

This probably should be refactored and the two classes should be separated (one class handling many_many and the other has_many).